# Sum over permuted indices

Tags: symbolic, summation, combinatorics, code-request, permutation

Consider this rank 6 tensor: $g_{ab}g_{cd}g_{ef}$.

Now I'd like to have a code to sum over all possible $6!$ permutations of the six indices with some coefficient $f[i]$, where $1 \leq i \leq 720$...  the output should be something like:

`f[1]g[[a,b]]g[[c,d]]g[[e,f]] + f[2]g[[a,f]]g[[c,d]]g[[e,b]] +..other 718 terms..`

Any help would be greatly appreciated..
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```
Clear[a, b, c, d, e, f, h, xss, g, p]
xss = Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {6}] // Map[Partition[#, 2] &]
p[n_, ps_] := h[n] Times @@ Map[Part[g, Sequence @@ #] &, ps]
ys = MapThread[p, {Range@Length@xss, xss}] // Quiet
ys // Total
```

Out:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MapIndexed` for this task:

```
func[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_}, {n_}] := ff[n] g[a, b] g[c, d] g[e, f]
Total@MapIndexed[func, Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e, f}]]
```

Comment: This is more or less what I had.